# How to use non default google credentials for Firestore?

Tags: .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an ASP.NET application. I need to pass google credentials json string for the FirestoreDb instance.
My problem is, on the production I can't save any file on a server. I did use below code. But this one works only for the Firebase Auth.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<FirebaseApp>((provider) =>
{
    return FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json)
    });
});
...
// this WORKS!
var auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(firebaseApp);
// this FAILS!
var db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);
```

Based on this documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart, looks like I have to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, which holds credentials file location. This solution works on my machine. But, I can not use this solution on the Production (as I mentioned above).

Can you help to find any other solution? How to pass a Google service account credential to the FirestoreDB instance?

Update:

I am hosting on Digitalocean App platform as an docker image.
Current limitation is, I can't copy files to the server (behind the scene it is k8s). Plus, they do not allow to deploy private docker hub images.

Comment: Google expects you to be able to set envvars in your environments, and so would I. I'm not familiar with asp but there must be some mechanism to set environment variables.

Comment: I can update env var. But problem is I have to save the credential file somewhere. It is Digitalocean App platform and my app is a docker image. There is no option to copy any file during deployment. I updated my question.

Comment: If I recall correctly that envvar can be a file location or the base64 encoded file (or there's a different envvar for the string). Then it's just like any other secret.

Comment: Maybe you might need to talk to your hosting provider to search a more feasible solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication with firestore for c# desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450519/authentication-with-firestore-for-c-sharp-desktop-app)